# Should I use a flyback diode for my PWM controlled universal motor?

Tags: pwm, dc-motor

I have a 500 watt universal motor powered by 80V DC source with a current draw of about 6 amps.
I now want to use a PWM switched MOSFET to control the motor speed.
Do I need a flyback diode to protect my circuit from high reverse voltage?
The motor will be run only in one direction.

Comment: The short answer is - yes. This question has been asked and answered several times, notably here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/93452/correct-use-of-flyback-or-snubber-diode-across-motor-or-transistor